# Loading partial via ajax inside parent partial loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial

I have added comments to my documents. When comments are submitted, a comments partial loads/updates via AJAX with the new comments. Inside this partial is a link to load a second partial (also loaded by ajax), to submit comments on comments (ie comment children).

When a new comment is added, the partial reloads with the new comments as expected, however the link to load the second partial does not work without reloading the page. I believe I need to delegate the first partial to a div or element in the document so that the javascript (to load the second partial) loads and is executed, how can i achieve this? Here is my setup:

**Create.js.erb:**

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= j comments(@document, @current_user) %>");
```

**Create action in comments Controller**

```
def create

  ....

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Inside of the comments partial, a second partial can be loaded, a form to submit children comments (ie. comments on comments).

**Link to trigger second partial/leave comment child (which is inside first partial)**

```
= link_to "Reply", {:controller => :documents, :action => :show}, { :method => :get, :remote => true}
```

**Show.js.erb:**

```
$('#comment_child_form_<%= @comment_parent.id %>').html("<%= j comment_child_form(@current_user, @document, @comment_parent) %>");
```

**Show Action in documents controller**

```
def show

  ....

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Notes: I am using Rails 3.2.12

Comment: it's not clear what rails version you use.

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34513/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17965127-loading-partial-via-ajax-inside-paren

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by combining my two js.erb files:

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= j comments(@document, @current_user) %>");
$('.reply-btn').click(function(){
  $('#comment_child_form_<%= @comment_parent.id %>').html("<%= j comment_child_form(@current_user, @document, @comment_parent) %>");
});
```

However, I am still unsure of how to delegate/append using jquery to an existing fixed html element (not inside of partial) (eg. 'body') so that all the other javascript is included (and executable) in the loaded partial. Any workarounds for this would be greatly appreciated.